# I got a error is null when trying to get data by html agility pack,Who solve it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack, development-environment

Html code:

```
<h2 class="di-title cdo-section-title-hw">appeal</h2>
```

C# code:

```
string url = "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/appeal";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(url);
var infor = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "h2" && n.Attributes["class"].Value == "di-title").FirstOrDefault();
Assets.ClassHttpAgilityPack http = new Assets.ClassHttpAgilityPack();
txtword.Text = infor.FirstChild.InnerText;

txtword.Text=null;
```

Comment: Maybe that `h2` doesn't exist? If you definitely want a node to be there, use `First()` not `FirstOrDefault()` so you immediately get and error if it does not exist. Or use `FirstOrDefault()` and check `if(infor != null){...}`

Comment: Not success. Still have error this.

Comment: I got this n.name= "#text"

Comment: @Rhumborl hey. if put First() then still error.

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Post the full exception.

Comment: @John Saunders: Null from infor.

Answer (score 1):

The `h2` does not have `class="di-title"`, it has `class="di-title cdo-section-title-hw"`. Therefore the node is not found. You should check if it *contains* that class rather than being equal to it. For safety you should also check if the attribute exists.

```
var infor = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "h2"
    && n.Attributes["class"] != null
    && n.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("di-title")).FirstOrDefault();
```